# Parsing XML of different formats using Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm writing a python class to parse XML and pull out tag names and their values. So far I have just been passing XML **files** to my class and parsing it using ElementTree.

Inevitably I'd like to be able to pass a variety of XML formats to the class, so not only files but possibly XML strings or XML from URL's.

I'm not sure what would be the best way to go about this. I was thinking of writing a seperate class or def to convert all XML information to a single format e.g string. Then have my parsing class set up just to accept XML strings for parsing.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to best solve this question that would be great and how to do it would be even better :).

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to get out? XML files with different formats likely just *mean* completely different things...

Comment: "writing a python class to parse XML".  Really?  Why?  Python has numerous XML parsers.  Why write another one?

Comment: @S.Lott because it does other things as well :)

Comment: "it does other things as well".  Usually a bad idea.  Most folks use an existing parser and add "other things" to it.  An import design principle is "Separation of Concerns".  If you separate parsing from "other things", then the parsing problem is solved.  What are these "other things"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LXML](http://lxml.de/). It can parse XML from strings, files or URLs, out of the box.

```
from lxml import etree
from cStringIO import StringIO

xml = """<foo><bar/> baz!</foo>"""

# parse from string
etree.fromstring(xml)

# parse from file-like; in this case, StringIO
s = StringIO(xml)
etree.parse(s)

# parse from URL
etree.parse("http://example.com/somefile.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, that's pretty much what I was after.

Answer (score 3):

i don't know why are you trying to parse xml by building your custom class. They are many xml parsers available in python like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [lxml](http://lxml.de/). You can use xpath expressions or css expressions with lxml.

**parsing xml response from url or file**

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
et = etree.parse(your xml file or your url)
value = et.xpath("xpath expression")
print value
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I seem to have written my question poorly. I am not writing my own parser, as I mentioned I'm using ElementTree (xml). I just wish to know what's the prefered way to deal with different formats of xml. larsmans, covered it well.Thanks.

Comment: @user788462: "I seem to have written my question poorly".  Please **update** the question.  Don't add important facts in the comments to an answer.